# индексы в mysql

Tags: mysql, база-данных, оптимизация, индексация

как известно, если в таблицу добавляется запись, то пересчитываются индексы и сбрасывается кэш запросов, чем больше таблица - тем больше времени это занимает.

вопрос 1: при каком количестве строк в таблице начнут ощущаться тормоза при вставке записей в таблицу? есть ли примерные соотношения, например, в таблицу с 3 индексами и 10кк строк insert выполняется 1,5с или есть какие то формулы?

вопрос 2: есть ли возможность сделать индексы не пересчитываемыми? например, id (primary key), на сколько я понимаю не пересчитывается т.к. мы знаем какой он будет (не меньше предыдущего, сортировать ничего не надо). можно ли сделать тоже самое, например, с timestamp со значением по умолчанию CURRENT_TIMESTAMP в целях уменьшения издержек на пересчёт индексов?

вопрос 3: есть ли какие то механизмы что бы "смягчать" нагрузку на большие таблицы где требуются индексы? например есть индекс на 10кк записей, каждый insert добавляется в временный "спрятанный" индекс который по достижению 10к элементов совмещается с основным, то есть вместо обновления огромного индекса создаётся маленький и через некоторое время совмещаются. теоретически это было бы в разы быстрее пересчёта индекса каждый insert

Comment: Нет - на все три вопроса. *если в таблицу добавляется запись, то пересчитываются индексы* Не пересчитываются, а обновляются. *сбрасывается кэш запросов* Нет, просто зависимые результаты объявляются невалидными. *например, id (primary key), на сколько я понимаю не пересчитывается т.к. мы знаем какой он будет (не меньше предыдущего, сортировать ничего не надо)* Это только для автоинкремента при отсутствии прямого присвоения. Впрочем, знание ни на что не влияет, да и знаем - лишь с некоторой вероятностью (autoincrement gaps).

Comment: *каждый insert добавляется в временный "спрятанный" индекс который по достижению 10к элементов совмещается с основным* Вы уж почитайте хоть что-нибудь про то, как организованы индексы, что такое "страницы", и что такое split/merge pages.

Comment: `сбрасывается кэш запросов` - да не существует его уже давно, забудьте.

Comment: @Мелкий кто то его украл? Вы перед тем как делать такие заявления попробуйте почитать документацию, или проверить самостоятельно.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков , https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html `The query cache is deprecated as of MySQL 5.7.20, and is removed in MySQL 8.0.`

Comment: @Мелкий спасибо за наводку, значит обновлять MySQL до 8 версии мне противопоказано, придется и дальше использовать 5.х. т.к. кэш дает ощутимый прирост производительности.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, на всякий случай - а он у вас точно включен? Просто его по-умолчанию выключили ещё в 5.6.8 и далее его надо было включать в конфиге вручную.

Comment: @Мелкий точно включен, конфигурация далека от "умолчаний" =) размер БД и нагрузка не те чтобы бросить всё по умолчанию =) + Много требований делать отчет